# After Xcode 6.3 Update it is Asking for download iOS 7.1 Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

As I already downloaded iOS 7.1 Simulator in Xcode 6.1 and it is working fine also But after Updating to Xcode 6.3.1 it is not showing up iOS 7.1 in Device list Why it is so?

it is asking me to download it again 7.1 simulator which is 819 MB..!

Any help guys? **or it is the Apple way?**

Comment: Download it then.  It doesn't normally happen, but there must be a reason.

Comment: Yes @trojanfoe..Do I have any choice?

Comment: As if you update Xcode for latest version, in last some version xCode, user to download existing Simulators, coz the path for that also has change for stored data.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you upgrade Xcode.

**What you can do**
If you still have Xcode 6.1 copied to somewhere:

1. **right-click** on it
2. Show Package Contents > Contents > Developer > **Applications**
3. There the iOS Simulator is located. Paste it into the new Xcode (same path)

Hope that helps :)